# Appgyver: Can't display images

Tags: ionic-framework, steroids

I have an appgyver app that I've tried to display images via

```
<img src="app/common/assets/pic.jpg"/>
<img src="common/assets/pic.jpg"/>
<img src="assets/pic.jpg"/>
<img src="pic.jpg"/>
<img src="http://www.somegoogleimage.com/pic.jpg"/>
```

Nothing shows. I'm confused out of my wits! I've also tried ng-src directive as source. Help !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

create a folder in your supersonic project
app/common/assets/images
Put your images in app/common/assets/images
src =/images/yourimage.jpg

Comment: As a rule of thumb, `dist/example/file.txt` will be served from `http://localhost/example/file.txt` in your device.